# Should fonts be served from a cookieless subdomain?

Tags: fonts, static-content

Why is it that that nobody ever mentions serving fonts over a cookieless (sub)domain?

Is it because you have to white-list your primary domain with [Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) for font files?

I'm asking because I want to know if there's some reason not to do it.

Comment: You've answered your own question `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` - most people do not know that this is a requirement.

Comment: This also applies when setting up fonts on a CDN which is more common than using a sub domain due to even more speed benefits.

Comment: I see. Thanks for confirming my suspicion. And that's a good point on the topic of CDNs.

Answer (score 1):

It doesnt have to be a subdomain, but you want to serve all your static resources (javascript, fonts, images, and css) from a different domain (subdomain or totally different).   The reason you do this is because when your site sets a cookie on its main domain, that cookie is sent back and forth on every possible request.   Since static resources (fonts, css, javascript) dont do much with server side cookies (unless if you change your webservers handler mappings), then you dont want to waste the extra bandwidth by sending the cookie data with every request.  Also not having cookies on these requests allows for proper caching by browsers and proxies.

Good practice dictates using a real domain for your site, and then a cookieless domain for all other static resrouces which are the same to all visitors.  Eventually you can move that content to a CDN like cloudfront and get some speed improvements.   If you use a CDN like MaxCDN they have features which strip cookies for you.